# Is Gaussian AR(1) Process Squared Stationary?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

If $X(t)$ is a Gaussian AR(1) process with Variance=1 and $\alpha=1/2$ and $Y(t)=X^2(t)$, is Y(t) also stationary?

Comment: Write down $X(t)$ as an infinite sum of white noise errors. Then multiply them, and the compute the mean, variance, and covariance. If they do not depend on $t$, it is.